# facebook android sdk application id error

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.1

I have added the application id string and put that to my manifesto file, even after that also i am getting applicationid error

Here is a trace from logcat

```
09-06 05:11:49.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1600): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 05:11:49.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1600): Process: com.mydomain.myapp, PID: 1600
09-06 05:11:49.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1600): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start 
03274activity ComponentInfo{com.mydomain.myapp/mydomain.myapp.FbShare}:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument 'applicationId' cannot be null
```

Also is there anything else i have to do before using facebook share dialog?

Check: (I had followed )
a) Adding FaceBook SDK Library
b) Created App on Facebok Developer, (with hash key etc )

c) Declaring use permissions for internet, adding application id in strings.xml and manifesto file.

Please help Thanks

Edit 1: (How i am calling the share dialog of facebook )
Here is the pastebin [calling facebook share dialog from the android activity](http://pastebin.com/0ZaHajMM)

Comment: post your manifest code

Comment: hi, here it is the manifesto http://pastebin.com/cT6idZqh